# Unclickable border between list items

Tags: html, css

I can't work out why the border between my list items isn't clickable. I've managed it in the past, but even looking at previous efforts isn't helping me see it. I've tried box-sizing, using flex like older working navigation menus, increasing heights - with no luck. I could write it again, or copy code from my last effort and I'm sure it would work, but I wouldn't learn why it's not behaving as I expected if I did.

https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/GQVPdO?editors=1100

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header .site-nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

header .site-nav li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}

header .site-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: #85d16c;
}

.site-nav li:hover,
.site-nav li:focus {
  background-color: rgba(133, 209, 108, 0.1);
}

.site-nav li:hover::before,
.site-nav li:focus::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(133, 209, 108, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the border on the `a` link in the list item itself:

```
header .site-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ssergei/pen/dmbMje

Comment: I swear I tried that! What's odd is that I've almost identical css that has the border on the li... But yeah, thanks for that - can't believe I missed it

Answer (score 0):

It is because the element you want to have border around is outside of the link tag. Try something like that instead:

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header .site-nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

header .site-nav li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


header .site-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: #85d16c;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(133, 209, 108, 0.1);
}

.site-nav li:hover::before,
.site-nav li:focus::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(133, 209, 108, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><li>Support</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Log In</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the border to click through like your links, then put the border on the links instead of the list items. A border on an `<li>` is part of the `<li>` and doesn't have default click behavior.

```
header .site-nav{ 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

header .site-nav li{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;  */ /* DELETE THIS */
}

header .site-nav a{
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

[Pen here.](https://codepen.io/75th/pen/ZxzWmB?editors=1100)